# Trigger.io microphone access

Tags: android, html, ios, microphone, trigger.io

Is there anyway to access a devices microphone with trigger.io. Possibly by using the native plugin feature and wrapping access to the microphone with a forge native api, or possibly another way.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to develop a plug-in.

Trigger.io - https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/index.html

Android - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

iOS - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html